# Binding nested JSON using JQUERY and Repopulating the other controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, nested

I have a dropdownlist in datalist, here i'm binding dropdown with JSON using jquery (structure is given below)

**JSON Formatted string:**

```
var hints = [{"term_id":2, [{"imagename": demoimg.png}]}];
```

in dropdown i'm binding `term_id`, if i selects `term_id (2)` then how i can bind `imageName` in image control (it is outside the `datalist`), on its selection based, using the same JSON string.

Comment: Please show us the code you already have (binding the dropdown with JSON using jquery)

Comment: this JSON is in nested form. [{"term_id":2, [{"imagename": demoimg.png}], "term_id":3,"term_id":4}];

Comment: WTF is "nested form" of JSON? Your array with the imagename has no key.